# version mismatch error from rebar get-deps

Tags: erlang, rebar

when I run `rebar get-deps` I get this error message:

```
WARN:  /home/me/test/deps/epcap/src/epcap.app.src has version "1.0.0"; requested regex was 0.7.9
WARN:  /home/me/test/deps/epcap/src/epcap.app.src has version "1.0.0"; requested regex was 0.7.9
ERROR: Dependency dir /home/me/test/deps/epcap failed application validation with reason:
{version_mismatch,{"/home/me/test/deps/epcap/src/epcap.app.src",
               {expected,"0.7.9"},
               {has,"1.0.0"}}}
```

I am new to this kind of programming and could not find much answers online. any help much appreciated

Comment: Are you using `rebar3` or ol' `rebar`? If you're using `rebar`, please consider switching to `rebar3` or `erlang.mk`, which are way more modern and actively maintained.

Comment: I'm using the old version I'll try with rebar3, thanks

Comment: I did `git clone https://github.com/erlang/rebar3.git` but still get the same error

Comment: I don't think `rebar3` and `rebar` have compatible config files, also, just by cloning rebar3 you're not going to suddenly be able to run it/interact with the project. Please share the rebar.config file too if you can